# Can we put a flow inside a LWC component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Can we put a flow inside a LWC?, I see a lot of references where flows can be added in Aura components and where LWC can be added inside Flows, but can I add a flow inside a LWC ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now (as of Spring '20), the answer is "no." You'll need to use an Aura component for this purpose.

Comment: Is it supported now ?

Comment: @Ajay It doesn't appear to be so.

Comment: Is there an update on this? I can't find anything and I don't want to involve an Aura components unless it's necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think this is supported. Aura components are going to be there and this fits definitely to use aura Component as shell for the flow.

Also record pages provide standard flow component that can be dragged and flow embeds into it.